# php - is it possible to create private final class field?

Tags: php, oop

How to create immutable objects in `php`?

Next example, of course, will not work.

```
  final class Beer {
    private $volume;
    // can it be like
    // private final $volume;
    // ?

    public function __construct($volume)
    {
      $this->volume = $volume;
      print('<h1>Object created.</h1>');
    }
  }

  $instance = new Beer(1)
```

Comment: Is your aim to create `Beer::$volume` such that it can be set once in the constructor but never overwritten later?

Comment: @mberkowski Yes, I want to construct an completely immutable object that  couldn't be changed after construction at all. Getter's will be used to retrieving encapsulated data.

Answer (score 1):

on php7.1, you can define your class constants with access modifiers (public, private or protected)

```
final class Beer {

 const volume ='xxxxxxxx' ; 
    public function __construct($volume)
    {

      echo self::volume;
      print('<h1>Works!</h1>');
    }
  }

  $instance = new Beer(1)
```

Comment: `self::volume . $volume;` has no effect.